# How to modify edge labels in Digraph of networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I am plotting a graph using matplotlib and graphviz. The working is fine but I want to get rid of label text on the edges.

**Output:**

[image]

I just want weights (those numbers on edges) to be shows without any extra labels. They are sometimes unreadable.
I tried multiple tricks but couldn't remove them.

**Code:**

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot, graphviz_layout
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

my_graph = nx.DiGraph()
my_graph.add_weighted_edges_from([("single1", "double1", 0), ("double1", "single2", 0), ("double1", "double3", 2), ("single2", "double3", 0), (
    "double2", "double4", 1), ("double2", "double5", 3), ("double3", "double5", 2), ("double4", "double6", 1), ("double4", "double6", 4)])


write_dot(my_graph, "graph.dot")

plt.title("draw graph")
pos = graphviz_layout(my_graph, prog='dot')
# labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(my_graph, 'w')


# nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(my_graph, pos, labels=labels)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(my_graph, pos)

nx.draw(my_graph, pos, with_labels=False, arrows=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(my_graph, pos)


plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Commented code is what I tried something to at least shorten the label text but it did not effect the graph at all.

**Required Output:**

> A similar graph with only weights(numbers) visible on edges. Or
> at-least with shorter edge labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `pygraphviz` yet but I hope this general solution will work for you.

`networkx` package allows to look up edge attributes in many ways like:

- `my_graph.edges.data()` - list of tuples that contains dictionaries of edge attributes
- `my_graph.edges.data('weight')` - list of tuples that contains specific attribute values
- `nx.get_edge_attributes(my_graph,'weight')` - similar to previous, in a dictionary form.

Documention of [draw_networkx_edge_labels](http://edge_labels%20(dictionary)) lists all the parameters, one of them is:

> *edge_labels (dictionary) - Edge labels in a dictionary keyed by edge two-tuple of text labels (default=None). Only labels for the keys in the dictionary are drawn.*

I think it's not that hard to guess which form should be inputted at this point. Use:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(my_graph, pos, edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(my_graph,'weight'))
```

So, after all, I think you were pretty close :)

Comment: this worked, but can you tell me why my previous code (commented one) wasn't effecting the output?

Comment: `labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(my_graph, 'w')` does nothing because edges don't have attribute `w`.

Comment: More clearly, it assigns an empty dict to `labels`